# scipy.signal not defined, but works after importing skimage

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I would like to use `scipy.signal.convolve2d()` function from [SciPy](https://scipy.org/), but `signal` is undefined:

```
>>> import scipy
...
>>> conv = scipy.signal.convolve2d(data, kernel, mode="same")

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line n, in <module>
    conv = scipy.signal.convolve2d(data, kernel, mode="same")
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'signal'.
```

But when I add skimage import:

```
from skimage.morphology import square
```

or

```
from skimage.morphology import disk
```

It suddenly starts to be defined, and works fine. Any ideas why and how to fix it properly, so it wouldn't need unused import? Skimage is a totally different thing, not related (at least in theory).

Lib versions:

```
scikit-image              0.19.2           py37hf11a4ad_0    anaconda
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py37hf11a4ad_1
scipy                     1.7.3            py37h0a974cb_0
```

Python version:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: scikit-image lists as Anaconda; is SciPy also installed from the default (Anaconda) channel, or from e.g. conda-forge? And are you using Anaconda, or e.g. Miniconda? Your OS is Windows, if I read it correctly?

Comment: I tried to install from different sources, before it wasn't from anaconda, and was the same. It's Windows 10.

Comment: What are "different sources" here? Different channels? PyPI? Build from source?

Comment: PIP, Conda-Forge, Anaconda. These were the ones that I tried. Couldn't find any information about that problem anywhere. Maybe it's Python version specific?

Comment: Have you tried `import scipy.signal` instead of `import scipy`? (Probably once you've removed the scikit-image package, or in a new environment with just SciPy.)

Comment: ok it works, but why? seems that it's not defined in main `init` ... and why importing skimage submodule fixes it?

Comment: Sometimes you need to explicitly import a subpackage. That's a design decision by the (SciPy) developers, probably to not pollute the namespace or save a bit of time when you only need to import a select part of SciPy. `skimage` probably imports `scipy.signal` under the hood, so the subpackage is available in the namespace.

Comment: Ok thank You for the solution, that will do it, at least won't need to install unnecessary modules. If You would like to make an answer from it, I will accept it. If not, I will delete the question in 10 minutes.

Comment: scipy is a large package, that's one of the reason it's broken down into smaller module and - because of lazy loading - it does not import everything with a top level import. `from scipy.signal import convolve2d` is a good way of important all you need, and no more

Comment: yeah I am using more than that and importing every function I need separately is a bit troublesome, this is the only thing that is not defined in `__init__.py`, at least from the ones that I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
import scipy.signal
```

to make sure you import the SciPy Signal subpackage.

`import skimage` probably imports `scipy.signal` under the hood, so the subpackage is available in the namespace; normally, you need to do this yourself.